# Using normal distribution in r

Tags: r

I am using rnorm but the outputs I receive are sometimes negative. How do I create a restriction so that the outputs cannot be below 0? Example:

```
output = rnorm(1, 800/20, sqrt(800))
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a normal distribution. Consider a different one `? Distributions`. Otherwise rescale your `output` vector after the fact: `output + abs(min(output))`

Answer (score 2):

Why not `abs(rnorm(1, 800/20, sqrt(800))`? `rnorm` was written to give numbers from a normal distribution. Perhaps you are looking to get output from a truncated distribution. In that case, you might want to have a look at the [`truncnorm`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncnorm/index.html) package.

```
library(truncnorm)
rtruncnorm( 1, a=0, b=Inf, 800/20, sqrt(800))

x = seq(-20,200,by=0.01)
y = dtruncnorm(x, a=0, b=Inf, 800/20, sqrt(800) )
plot(x,y,type="l",main="Density of a truncated normal distribution")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Poisson distribution takes only positive values. Otherwise golbasche solution seems perfect.

```
hist(rpois(100, 5))
```